Non-existence of power divided structure on a maximal ideal of truncated polynomial rings (example from Koblitz)
In 3.3 of Berthelot-Ogus's book Notes on Crystalline Cohomology, an example from Koblitz is exhibited without proof.
Let $k$ be a field (or a commutative ring) with characteristic $p>0$, $$A:=k[x_1,\dots,x_6]/(x_1^p,\dots,x_6^p,x_1x_2+x_3x_4+x_5x_6)$$
with ideal $I:=(x_1,\dots,x_6)\subset A$. Show that there can be no divided power structure on ideal $I$.
I tried some ways but can't deduce a contradiction. Actually I'm quite curious what techniques can be utilized to prove non-existence of a PD structure on an ideal.

Suppose that $I$ admits a divided power structure. On the one hand, $\gamma_p(x_1x_2+x_3x_4+x_5x_6)$ has to be equal to zero because the element $x_1x_2+x_3x_4+x_5x_6$ is zero in our ring, but let's evaluate $\gamma_p(x_1x_2+x_3x_4+x_5x_6)$ using the binomial formula:
$$\gamma_p(x_1x_2+x_3x_4+x_5x_6)=\gamma_p(x_1x_2)+\gamma_p(x_3x_4)+\gamma_p(x_5x_6)+\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i+j+m=p \\ 0\leq i,j,m<p}\frac{1}{i!j!m!}(x_1x_2)^i(x_3x_4)^j(x_5x_6)^m$$
The first three summands are zero, because $\gamma_p(x_1x_2)=x_1^p\gamma_p(x_2)=0$, regardless of what $\gamma_p(x_2)$ is. The last sum is non-zero though: we can see this e.g. by replacing $x_5x_6$ with $-x_1x_2-x_3x_4$ and using that $A$ contains the ring $k[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]/(x_1^p,x_2^p,x_3^p,x_4^p)$ as a subring. The coefficient of the monomial $(x_1x_2)^{p-1}x_3x_4$ in this sum is $$\sum\limits\limits_{i=0}^{p-1}\frac{(-1)^{p-1-i}}{i!(p-1-i)!}+ \sum\limits\limits_{i=1}^{p-1}\frac{(-1)^{p-i}}{i!(p-i)!}(p-i)=-1$$
So this sum is nonzero, and $\gamma_p(x_1x_2+x_3x_4+x_5x_6)$ cannot be zero, giving us a contradiction.
Note that the analogous computation for the ring $k[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]/(x_i^p,x_1x_2+x_3x_4)$ would actually give zero, and the maximal ideal of this ring does have a divided power structure. For more on divided power structures on truncated local rings of quadrics see section 3.2 in this paper of Zdanowicz https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.05104

Beautiful answer! Thx. I did essentially the same computation but missed the point $A$ contains a "free" truncated algebra, whence stuck in hideous ideal membership checking... And this cited paper (especially 3.2.2) contains some very nice answers to this question.
